# How to get all queries used in a transaction on Snowflake?

Tags: transactions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way on Snowflake to get all DML operations of a transaction into a table ?

If I am having a transaction with 3 inserts, I need to run a query that will result in getting 3 rows with some metadata of the DML itself.

Comment: You can use the  CHANGES clause which enables querying the change tracking metadata for a table   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/changes.html

Answer (score 1):

stream is used to capture transactions on snowflake-

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html#stream-ddl

Answer (score 1):

You can get all queries executed in a transaction on Snowflake with the following query template:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY
WHERE TRANSACTION_ID = ?
```

Alternatively, as a function:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION QUERY_HISTORY_BY_TRANSACTION(TRANSACTION_ID VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE(QUERY_ID VARCHAR)
AS $$
    SELECT QH.QUERY_ID
    FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY AS QH
    WHERE QH.TRANSACTION_ID = TRANSACTION_ID
$$;
```

which could be used as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY
    INNER JOIN TABLE(QUERY_HISTORY_BY_TRANSACTION('<id>'))
        USING (QUERY_ID)
```

The view [QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history) also has many other columns which may be useful for your purposes: QUERY_TYPE, QUERY_TEXT, QUERY_TAG, EXECUTION_STATUS, ROWS_INSERTED, etc. However, note that "Latency for the view may be up to 45 minutes."

Finally, you can get a transaction ID with the function [LAST_TRANSACTION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/last_transaction),
the function [CURRENT_TRANSACTION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/current_transaction), or the statement [SHOW TRANSACTIONS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-transactions). The function LAST_TRANSACTION is arguably the most useful for scripting, whereas the statement SHOW TRANSACTIONS may be more usable in interactive workflows.